# What do interannual, annual and intrannual and interseasonal, seasonal and intraseasonal mean in the context of Oceanography?

Tags: oceanography, sea-level, seasons, enso

Currently I am studying the period of oceanographic phenomena such as El Niño, and I have seen the next concepts: interannual, annual and intrannual and interseasonal, seasonal and intraseasonal. I can understand some of them, but I would like someone could help me to understand them very well  in the context of Oceanography.
Maybe if you provide me with some literature about those definitions it would be great? Thanks.

Comment: I changed the wording of the question to "what do they mean", because I think you are asking about the meaning, not mean values. If I was wrong, just change it back.

Comment: "Intra" means inside, "Inter" means between or crossing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is literature, apart from dictionaries, it's simple semantics:

- interannual: from year to year
- annual: yearly
- intrannual: during the course of a year
- interseasonal: from season to season, or between seasons
- seasonal: during a season
- intraseasonal: during a season

The seasonal stuff can depend on the context, as seasons fall differently over the surface of the earth. It also depends on context if someone is talking about a point in time, or a period, a punctual observation or a trend or development. These terms just help framing (that's a cool word) the subject at hand.